# Heroku Jammit GEM with the latest Heroku Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jammit

I've been using the following heroku jammit gem for deploying:

```
https://github.com/kylejginavan/heroku_jammit/blob/master/lib/heroku_jammit.rb
```

During a nightly deployment, heroku had me update my heroku gem, which then broke this jammit gem. I now get the following error:

```
===== Deploying assets for  to heroku...

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
[FAIL]
===== Done...
===== Deleting compiled assets...[OK]
===== Commiting deleted assets...[OK]
===== Done...
```

**In the heroku_jammit gem '/lib/heroku_jammit.rb'**

```
line 84: run "git push git@heroku.com:#{@app}.git #{branch}:master"
```

Any suggestions on how to update this line to work with the new heroku gem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API of the Heroku gem changed. Before 2.0 `@app` was defined with an `attr_reader`. In version 2.0+ it's a method. The fix is to change the instance variable call to `@app` to a method call to `app`.

We fixed this in our [pull request](https://github.com/kylejginavan/heroku_jammit/pull/4) which has been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution is hard and dirty, but I found out, that @app is not defined anymore(inside the plugin). If you have a remote stage and a production head, heroku always ask me: please add -app [app-name] to specify....I tried it and it worked for me....

1. the plugin lives in your users-home-folder: ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku_jammit
2. goto ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku_jammit/lib/heroku_jammit.rb and add following line(near 78):
   heroku_jammit.rb:

   def deploy

   fail_if_jammit_not_installed!

   is_root?

   branch = set_branch

after this write:

```
@app=@options[:app]
```

and you can commit with:

```
heroku jammit:deploy --app [your-app-name]
```

I'm on rails 2.3.11, ruby-1.8.7-p334 (with rvm) - in development everything works fine.
On heroku I get erros with assets.yml. I tried all jammit version from 0.4.4 to now, but I stuck and look now for a new solution.

Good luck....